# If "to make larger" is "enlarge", what is the term "to make complete"?

Tags: word-request

I was almost incorrectly using the word "encomplete", but then I tried to search and found out that that word is non-existent. Is there perhaps any term for "to make complete" similar with "enlarge" is for "to make larger"?

Answer (score 2):

The word is simply the transitive verb "complete", without a prefix:
[American Heritage Dictionary *complete*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=complete)

> 1. To bring to a finish or an end:
>    *She has completed her studies.*
> 2. To make whole, with all necessary elements or parts:
>    *A second child would complete their family.
>
>    Fill in the blanks to complete the form.*

If you look for synonyms of "complete" as a verb, you will see many other words that share the basic meaning, such as *end, complement, finish, achieve, settle* etc.

Comment: Ah, yeah, when I think again about it, I can say "I want to enlarge this font", but I also can say "I want to complete this task". Thank you for clarifying!